# How to pass parameter as environment variable from upstream job to downstream job in jenkins? without downstream jobs being parametrized

Tags: jenkins, environment

I am using a parametrized job to trigger pipeline jobs job1,job2 and job3. My intention is that by default job1,job2,job3 should run on node "A" and whenever I use parametrized job, and select node "B" manually then all downstream jobs i,e job1,job2 and job3 should run on the node "B".

I used `nodelabel` parameter plugin but only parent job will run accordingly as selected parameter but downstream jobs are not triggered on the selected parameter in the parent job.

Answer (score 1):

Make a job parameter for job1, job2 and job3. Use this parameter for nodelabel. Make the default for this parameter nodeB. When you start the job with the parametrized job set the parameter nodeA as seen below:

```
build job: 'job1', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name:'nodeA']]
```

Comment: For this down stream jobs need to be parametrized right? but I don't want downstream job to be parametrized.

Comment: No, they accept parameters even if they aren´t parametrized.